# How I find my running jar file path on unix?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a.jar file. I want to its path where ever it is when it running.

I use this code :
 `System.getProperty("user.dir")` it works in windows but not work in unix

Comment: `locate yourfile.jar` or `dir c:\yourfile.jar /s /a /p`?

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Reported for closing.

Comment: no duplicate , I see it but it doesnt I want.
I use this code : System.getProperty("user.dir") it works in windows but not work in unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really really need this, here's a solution:

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

It is, however, far from pretty ;). Consider using other mechanisms. (Source: [a slideset of mine](http://www.slideshare.net/miquelmartin/java-pitfalls-and-goodtoknows))

Answer (score 0):

the answer is :

in windows :

```
String yourJarName="yourJarName.jar"; 
String Jar_path= MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().replace(yourJarName,"").substring(1);
```

in unix :

```
   String yourJarName="yourJarName.jar"; 
    String Jar_path= MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().replace(yourJarName,"");
```